# How can I format received data using Object.keys?

Tags: javascript

I have this data:

```
const langs = {
    en: ['One', 'description'],
    pl: ['Jeden', 'opis'],
};
```

And I'm trying to parse it into this format:

```
const formattedData = {
    name: {
        en: "One",
        pl: "Jeden",
    },
    description: {
        en: "description",
        pl: "opis",
    }
};
```

I tried to do something like this:

```js
const langs = {
  en: ['One', 'description'],
  pl: ['Jeden', 'opis'],
};

const val = Object.keys(langs).map(item => ({
  [item]: langs[item][0]
}))

console.log(val);
```

Comment: Do you _really_ need to use `Object.keys` here or have you asked an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info)?

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `Object.entries` to get key, value pair and then add an object which has name and description keys already defined

```js
const langs = {
  en: ['One', 'description'],
  pl: ['Jeden', 'opis'],
};
let val = {name:{}, description:{}}
Object.entries(langs).forEach(([key,v])=>{
  val.name[key]=v[0]
  val.description[key]=v[1]
})
console.log(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could do it with `Object.keys`, as asked. You may need to create the target object structure in advance (or at least it's more readable to do so).

```js
const langs = {
  en: ['One', 'description'],
  pl: ['Jeden', 'opis'],
};
let newObj = {
  name: {},
  description: {}
};

Object.keys(langs).forEach(item => {
  newObj.name[item] = langs[item][0];
  newObj.description[item] = langs[item][1];
});

console.log(newObj);
```